# Displaying Images and Description in listview on html page from JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, css, parsing

I am newbie to javascript ,Help me to display image and description in list view on html page get from the json object  ..

Here i am parsed a json object and retrieved image URL and image description. Now I have to display the Image and Description in listview on html page. But I am Not getting How..Plese help me to solve this..

Here is My HTML Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jsonData.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(searchAPI);
    })
</script>

</head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="search1" value="search here"  >
    <button id="submit" >submit</button>
    <div id="div1">
    <img id="img"  src="http://hdcomputerwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Puppy- images.jpg"  style="width:200px;height:200px;">
    <p id="p2">  </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

My js file is:

```
 function searchAPI(){
var searchText= $("#search1").val();
alert(searchText);
$.getJSON('http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=ashok&format=json&pretty=1&callback=?',function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.RelatedTopics.length;i++) {
        var desc= data.RelatedTopics[i].Text;
        var url= data.RelatedTopics[i].Icon.URL;
    }
});
}
```

Please help me How to display this Image and Description in list view like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works for you.

modify js like :

```
function searchAPI(){
var searchText= $("#search1").val();
alert(searchText);
var htmlContent="<ul>"; 
$.getJSON('http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=ashok&format=json&pretty=1&callback=?',function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.RelatedTopics.length;i++) {
        var desc= data.RelatedTopics[i].Text;
        var url= data.RelatedTopics[i].Icon.URL;
        htmlContent += "<li><img src='" + url + "' style='width:100px;height:100px;display:inline-block'/> <p style='display:inline-block'>"+desc+"</p></li>";
    }
htmlContent += "</ul>";
$('#div1').html(htmlContent);
});
}
```